# Interrupt current TalkBack readout and begin new one?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have a reorderable `RecyclerView` and every time you move an item below or above another item, TalkBack will read out:

> "Moved *ItemTitle* above item 2".

The problem is that it queues all these readouts and executes them all. So if you move an item from position 12 to position 1 really quickly, it will say:

> "Moved *ItemTitle* above item 12. 
>   Moved *ItemTitle* above item 11. 
>   Moved *ItemTitle* above item 10. Moved *ItemTitle* above item 9..."

**How do I tell it to stop the current readout, clear the queue and just read the most recent announcement?**

This is the method which fires every time a `RecyclerView` item is dragged above or below another item.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {

    String direction = fromPosition < toPosition ? "below" : "above";
    String title1 = viewModel.get(fromPosition).getItemTitle();
    String title2 = viewModel.get(toPosition)).getItemTitle();

    // these announcements are queued 
    view.announceForAccessibility(view.getContext().getString(R.string.on_move_draggable_item_announce, title1, direction, title2));

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
((AccessibilityManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE)).interrupt();
```

Before you announce like this:

```
view.announceForAccessibility(announcementMessage);
```